# How to Remove ^[ characters from a file using Linux shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Using Linux shell scripting, how can I remove the ^[ characters from something like this:

```
^[[0mCAM1> 
^[[0^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H
 rcv-multicast: 0
      tx-bytes: 33649974
    tx-packets: 99133
```

Comment: Do you want to remove ONLY ^[, or all of the escape sequences?

Comment: Where does this come from ? A file ? The `^[` is a symbol for escape (ASCII character 27/0x1B), and IIRC `^[[0m` is a sequence to reset the character color and attributes.

Comment: See [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-do-we-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell) question, it has better answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to remove chars from files like this:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/^[//g' somefile
```

The `-i ''` causes it to change the file *in-place* (not make a copy).

Answer (score 1):

You can make that with sed for example:

```
sed 's/^\[//g' oldfile > newfile;
mv newfile oldfile;
```

(it will remove only the trailing brackets, if you want to remove all of them, remove the `^` sign from the sed expression)

Answer (score 0):

You may remove these control characters by:

```
tr -d "[:cntrl:]" file.txt
```

however it'll remove also new line endings, so here is a trick, define this alias:

```
alias clean='tr "\r\n" "\275\276" | tr -d "[:cntrl:]" | tr "\275\276" "\r\n"'
```

then try like:

```
cat file.txt | clean > new_file.txt
```