# How to remove ^[, and all of the ANSI escape sequences in a file using linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

We want to remove  `^[`, and all of the escape sequences.

sed is not working and is giving us this error:

```
$ sed 's/^[//g' oldfile > newfile; mv newfile oldfile;
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

$ sed -i '' -e 's/^[//g' somefile
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Are you looking for two characters, caret `^` and open square bracket `[`, or are you looking for one character, control-[ (ASCII ESCAPE, 0x1B)?  Are you looking to remove the terminal control sequences that follow the ESC character?  If so, that is a complex job, and ultimately requires you to know which terminal the control codes were generated for - different terminal types use different control sequences, and for a single terminal type, different commands have different numbers of following characters.

Comment: This is not _such_ a difficult task  - it depends in part on the context.

Answer (score 72):

Are you looking for [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.html)?

---

Two things you can do: enter the literal escape (in bash:)

Using keyboard entry:

```
sed 's/Ctrl-vEsc//g'
```

*alternatively*

```
sed 's/Ctrl-vCtrl-[//g'
```

Or you can use character escapes:

```
sed 's/\x1b//g'
```

or for all [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters):

```
sed 's/[\x01-\x1F\x7F]//g' # NOTE: zaps TAB character too!
```

Comment: also asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998978/removing-colors-from-output

See ansifilter source: https://gitlab.com/saalen/ansifilter/

Answer (score 61):

[commandlinefu gives the correct answer](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12043/remove-color-special-escape-ansi-codes-from-text-with-sed) which strips ANSI colours as well as movement commands:

> ```
> sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g"
> ```

Comment: This works with gnu sed, but is not portable to other sed implementations (e.g., bsd) - because of the \x1B.  For other seds, you can use the raw escape character (you can use the ctrl-v prefix to insert a literal escape character on the command line).

Comment: Bash also lets you say `sed $'s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g'` where the dollar sign before the single quote is significant (it produces a "C-style" string).

Comment: @tripleee - thanks! this helped for macos(bsd) sed. Extending your example a bit further: sed $'s,[\x01-\x1F\x7F]\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" handles all escape sequences

Comment: I found this sed substitution left `^[(B` in /var/log/dnf.log output. The one by AGipson worked better for me.

Comment: `\x1B\[[?0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]` with `IGNORECASE` did the trick. As escape codes can be `\x1B[?25` for instance, the `?` being notable here.

Answer (score 22):

I managed with the following for my purposes, but this doesn't include all possible [ANSI escapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```
sed -r 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m?//g'
```

This removes `m` commands, but for all escapes (as commented by @lethalman) use:

```
sed -r 's/\x1b\[[^@-~]*[@-~]//g'
```

Also see "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857352/python-regex-to-match-vt100-escape-sequences".

There is also a [table of common escape sequences](https://web.archive.org/web/20200805075926/http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).

Comment: That only escapes the `m` command. This should be more generic `\x1b\[[^@-~]*[@-~]`

Comment: I specifically mentioned that it isn't generic— "...but this doesn't include all possible ANSI escapes..."

Comment: The `[^@-~]*[@-~]` didn't work for me; I needed `[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]` (which seems to match all the required characters in the table)

Comment: Note that on BSD (Mac OS X) sed doesn’t support ANSI-C escape sequences like `\x1b`. So in these environments one might need to lean on the shell a bit by having it expand the escape byte: `sed 's/'"$(printf '\x1b')"'\[[^@-~]*[@-~]//g'` — Tested on both BSD and GNU sed in bash4, seems to work fine.

Comment: In my situation of trying to delete the escape sequences in `unbuffer yum search`, I had to do `sed 's/\x1b\(\[\|(\)[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g'` (I couldn't get the syntax to work with `-r`). In addition to the adjustment by @DavidFraser, I not only had to remove stuff that started with `\x1b\[` but also stuff that started with `\x1b(`.

Answer (score 18):

ansi2txt command (part of kbtin package) seems to be doing the job perfectly on Ubuntu.

Comment: So `ansi2txt` appears to not to strip bold characters, whereas the answer using `col -b` listed below (perversely) does.  Here is a test case to demonstrate this: `diff <(man -Tutf8 tmux | col -b | head  | hd)  <(man -Tutf8 tmux | ansi2txt | head  | hd) `

Comment: It looks like piping `ansi2txt` to `col -b` is necessary to remove everything.

Comment: When piping `ansi2txt` to `col -b` you may want to use `col -xb` to prevent spaces getting replaced by tabs. But then tabs will be replaced with spaces.

Answer (score 12):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc/24005600#24005600) given by [Luke H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289203/luke-h), but I did want to share the regular expression that I've been using to eliminate all of the ASCII Escape Sequences.

```
sed -r 's~\x01?(\x1B\(B)?\x1B\[([0-9;]*)?[JKmsu]\x02?~~g'
```

Comment: This worked for Fedora's /var/log/dnf.log output, Tom Hale's answer left `^[(B` in the output.

Answer (score 11):

I've stumbled upon this post when looking for a way to strip extra formatting from man pages. ansifilter did it, but it was far from desired result (for example all previously-bold characters were duplicated, like `SSYYNNOOPPSSIISS`).

For that task the correct command would be `col -bx`, for example:

```
groff -man -Tascii fopen.3 | col -bx > fopen.3.txt
```

[*(source)*](http://www.schweikhardt.net/man_page_howto.html)

Why this works: (in response to a comment by @AttRigh)

`groff` produces bold characters like you would on a typewriter: print a letter, move one character back with backspace (you can't erase text on a typewriter), print the same letter again to make the character more pronounced. So simply omitting backspaces produces "SSYYNNOOPPSSIISS". `col -b` fixes this by interpreting backspaces correctly, quote from the manual:

> **-b** Do not output any backspaces, printing only the last character written to each column position.

Comment: It seems to be the `col -b` option that does this. The documentation says that this removes backspaces characters :/, go figure. It is nevertheless the most compact option that I could find that doesn't require one to install things (outside of one's package manager)

Comment: `i++` for this. Don't reinvent this wheel, folks. See also `colcrt`

Answer (score 10):

You can remove all non printable characters with this:

> `sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g'`

Comment: On Mac, using sed, this is the only answer that worked to remove the `\x1b` ascii escape characters.

Comment: But this only removes the invisible characters; so something like `^[[0;31m` will simply turn into `[0;31m`.

Comment: @tripleee you can add `....` and remove them. `'s/[^[:print:]]....//g'`

Comment: @rth Unclear what you are proposing; trimming exactly four characters is wrong because the escape sequences are different lengths. You'd have to write an escape sequence parser to know how many to remove.

Comment: @tripleee Ah yes, agree. But I was just looking for a simple solution to remove color sequences from an output, and for this primitive purpose, it works. Of course, it doesn't work for more general cases. Thank you for catching this.

Comment: Even then, you can't know whether it's a single-digit or double-digit number, as evidenced by the earlier example. You could wing it with something like `s/[^[:print;]]\[[0-9;]*[A-Za-z]//g` but I'm not sure that's entirely correct either.

Comment: If all you want to do is remove non-printables, you can also use `tr -dc '[:print:]'`.

Comment: So, I had some success on MAC with `sed 's/[^[:print:]]\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g' old.txt > new.txt`

Answer (score 6):

I built [vtclean](https://github.com/lunixbochs/vtclean) for this. It strips escape sequences using these regular expressions in order (explained in [regex.txt](https://github.com/lunixbochs/vtclean/blob/master/regex.txt)):

```
// handles long-form RGB codes
^\033](\d+);([^\033]+)\033\\

// excludes non-movement/color codes
^\033(\[[^a-zA-Z0-9@\?]+|[\(\)]).

// parses movement and color codes
^\033([\[\]]([\d\?]+)?(;[\d\?]+)*)?(.)`)
```

It additionally does basic line-edit emulation, so backspace and other movement characters (like left arrow key) are parsed.

Answer (score 5):

`sed` based approach without extended regular expressions enabled by `-r`

```
sed 's/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g'
```

Comment: That one is filtering nicely complex escape codes llike:`\033[38;2;255;255;255m ` where even iconv `iconv -f "ASCII" -t "UTF-8"` is failing. Thanks for posting

Comment: first 4 solution didn't  work, but this one does!

Answer (score 3):

Just a note; let's say you have a file like this (such line endings are generated by `git` remote reports):

```
echo -e "remote: * 27625a8 (HEAD, master) 1st git commit\x1b[K
remote: \x1b[K
remote: \x1b[K
remote: \x1b[K
remote: \x1b[K
remote: \x1b[K
remote: Current branch master is up to date.\x1b[K" > chartest.txt
```

In binary, this looks like this:

```
$ cat chartest.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  72 65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20  2a 20 32 37 36 32 35 61  |remote: * 27625a|
00000010  38 20 28 48 45 41 44 2c  20 6d 61 73 74 65 72 29  |8 (HEAD, master)|
00000020  20 31 73 74 20 67 69 74  20 63 6f 6d 6d 69 74 1b  | 1st git commit.|
00000030  5b 4b 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74  65 3a 20 1b 5b 4b 0a 72  |[K.remote: .[K.r|
00000040  65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20 1b  5b 4b 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74  |emote: .[K.remot|
00000050  65 3a 20 1b 5b 4b 0a 72  65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20 1b  |e: .[K.remote: .|
00000060  5b 4b 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74  65 3a 20 1b 5b 4b 0a 72  |[K.remote: .[K.r|
00000070  65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20 43  75 72 72 65 6e 74 20 62  |emote: Current b|
00000080  72 61 6e 63 68 20 6d 61  73 74 65 72 20 69 73 20  |ranch master is |
00000090  75 70 20 74 6f 20 64 61  74 65 2e 1b 5b 4b 0a     |up to date..[K.|
0000009f
```

It is visible that `git` here adds the sequence `0x1b` `0x5b` `0x4b` before the line ending (`0x0a`).

Note that - while you can match the `0x1b` with a literal format `\x1b` in sed, you CANNOT do the same for `0x5b`, which represents the left square bracket `[`:

```
$ cat chartest.txt | sed 's/\x1b\x5b//g' | hexdump -C
sed: -e expression #1, char 13: Invalid regular expression
```

You might think you can escape the representation with an extra backslash `\` - which ends up as `\\x5b`; but while that "passes" - it doesn't match anything as intended:

```
$ cat chartest.txt | sed 's/\x1b\\x5b//g' | hexdump -C
00000000  72 65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20  2a 20 32 37 36 32 35 61  |remote: * 27625a|
00000010  38 20 28 48 45 41 44 2c  20 6d 61 73 74 65 72 29  |8 (HEAD, master)|
00000020  20 31 73 74 20 67 69 74  20 63 6f 6d 6d 69 74 1b  | 1st git commit.|
00000030  5b 4b 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74  65 3a 20 1b 5b 4b 0a 72  |[K.remote: .[K.r|
00000040  65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20 1b  5b 4b 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74  |emote: .[K.remot|
...
```

So if you want to match this character, apparently you *must* write it as escaped left square bracket, that is `\[` - the rest of the values can than be entered with escaped `\x` notation:

```
$ cat chartest.txt | sed 's/\x1b\[\x4b//g' | hexdump -C
00000000  72 65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20  2a 20 32 37 36 32 35 61  |remote: * 27625a|
00000010  38 20 28 48 45 41 44 2c  20 6d 61 73 74 65 72 29  |8 (HEAD, master)|
00000020  20 31 73 74 20 67 69 74  20 63 6f 6d 6d 69 74 0a  | 1st git commit.|
00000030  72 65 6d 6f 74 65 3a 20  0a 72 65 6d 6f 74 65 3a  |remote: .remote:|
00000040  20 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74 65  3a 20 0a 72 65 6d 6f 74  | .remote: .remot|
00000050  65 3a 20 0a 72 65 6d 6f  74 65 3a 20 0a 72 65 6d  |e: .remote: .rem|
00000060  6f 74 65 3a 20 43 75 72  72 65 6e 74 20 62 72 61  |ote: Current bra|
00000070  6e 63 68 20 6d 61 73 74  65 72 20 69 73 20 75 70  |nch master is up|
00000080  20 74 6f 20 64 61 74 65  2e 0a                    | to date..|
0000008a
```

Answer (score 2):

[Tom Hale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43627833/856172) left unwanted codes, but was a good base to work from.  Adding additional filtering cleared out leftover, unwanted codes:

```
sed -e "s,^[[[(][0-9;?]*[a-zA-Z],,g" \
    -e "s/^[[[][0-9][0-9]*[@]//" \
    -e "s/^[[=0-9]<[^>]*>//" \
    -e "s/^[[)][0-9]//" \
    -e "s/.^H//g" \
    -e "s/^M//g" \
    -e "s/^^H//" \
        file.dirty > file.clean
```

As this was done on a non-GNU version of sed, where you see `^[`, `^H`, and `^M`, I used Ctrl-V <Esc>, Ctrl-V Ctrl-H, and Ctrl-V Ctrl-M respectively.  The `^>` is literally a carat (^) and greater-than character, not Ctrl-<.

TERM=xterm was in use at the time.

To remove PCL codes, add patterns like this:

```
sed -e "s/^[[&()*][a-z]*[-+]*[0-9][0-9]*[A-Z]//" \
    -e "s/^[[=9EZYz]//" \
        file.dirty > file.clean
```

Ideally, if the regular expressions are used with an interpreter that understands the **?** meta-character,  the first pattern is better expressed as:

```
      "s/^[[&()*][a-z]?[-+]?[0-9][0-9]*[A-Z]//" \
```

Answer (score 1):

A bash snippet I've been using for stripping out (at least some) ANSI colors:

```
shopt -s extglob
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  echo "${line//$'\x1b'\[*([0-9;])[Km]/}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer to

[What are these weird ha:// URLs jenkins fills our logs with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933467/what-are-these-weird-ha-urls-jenkins-fills-our-logs-with/)

removes all ANSI escape sequences from Jenkins console log files effectively (it also deals with Jenkins-specific URLs which wouldn't be relevant here).

I acknowledge and appreciate the contributions of [Marius Gedminas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110151/marius-gedminas) and [pyjama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612684/pyjama) from this thread in formulating the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

This simple awk solution worked for me, try this:

```
str="happy $(tput setaf 1)new$(tput sgr0) year!" #colored text
echo $str | awk '{gsub("(.\\[[0-9]+m|.\\(..\\[m)","",$0)}1' #remove ansi colors
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [astrp](https://git.sr.ht/%7Ekchibisov/astrp) CLI tool for stripping ANSI escape codes. astrp is built on top of Alacritty's VTE parser which passes the input through a state machine. This approach should be more robust than replacing escape codes with regular expressions.