# Python regex to match VT100 escape sequences

Tags: python, regex, vt100

I'm writing a Python program that logs terminal interaction (similar to the *script* program), and I'd like to filter out the VT100 escape sequences before writing to disk. I'd like to use a function like this:

```
def strip_escapes(buf):
    escape_regex = re.compile(???) # <--- this is what I'm looking for
    return escape_regex.sub('', buf)
```

What should go in `escape_regex`?

Comment: It's a bit complicated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_sequences

Comment: Check http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=186004 for a PHP version. It should be simple to convert it to python.

Comment: In the spirit of these other comments, here is also a TCL process that does exactly the same thing... http://wiki.tcl.tk/9673

Comment: Here's one that worked for me: `sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"` ([source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed))

Answer (score 5):

The combined expression for escape sequences can be something generic like this:

```
(\x1b\[|\x9b)[^@-_]*[@-_]|\x1b[@-_]
```

*Should be used with `re.I`*

This incorporates:

1. Two-byte sequences, i.e. `\x1b` followed by a character in the range of `@` until `_`.
2. One-byte CSI, i.e. `\x9b` as opposed to `\x1b + "["`.

However, this will not work for sequences that define key mappings or otherwise included strings wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

VT100 codes are already grouped(mostly) according to similar patterns here:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

I think the simplest approach would be to use some tool like regexbuddy to define a regex for each VT100 codes group.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution to successfully parse vt100 color codes and remove the non-printable escape sequences.  The code snippet found [here](http://atlas-computing.web.cern.ch/atlas-computing/links/buildDirectory/AtlasOffline/15.9.0/InstallArea/doc/PyCmt/html/namespacepython_1_1pyshell_1_1vt100.html) successfully removed all codes for me when running a telnet session using telnetlib:

```
    def __processReadLine(self, line_p):
    '''
    remove non-printable characters from line <line_p>
    return a printable string.
    '''

    line, i, imax = '', 0, len(line_p)
    while i < imax:
        ac = ord(line_p[i])
        if (32<=ac<127) or ac in (9,10): # printable, \t, \n
            line += line_p[i]
        elif ac == 27:                   # remove coded sequences
            i += 1
            while i<imax and line_p[i].lower() not in 'abcdhsujkm':
                i += 1
        elif ac == 8 or (ac==13 and line and line[-1] == ' '): # backspace or EOL spacing
            if line:
                line = line[:-1]
        i += 1

    return line
```

Comment: That won't work for some common initialization sequences, such as
    escape =
    escape >
    escape 7
    escape 8
as well as any *reset mode* control (ends with "l").  Those are listed in xterm's documentation: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html