# How to disable ansi colors when piping?

Tags: c, unix

Is there a way to detect if a program is piped into another one?
Because when I print a colored string using ANSI colors, the get piped
too, which I want to prevent.
Or is there a better way to print colors?

Comment: Note that some of the colourizing programs provide an option like `—color=always` with options such as `auto` and `off` as alternatives.

Comment: Take a look at this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some program do accept color when piped into ( like `less -r` ).

But in your case you would want to know if your current output is a tty, and use [`isatty`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) for that purpose, and avoid printing color when your output is not a terminal.

You will also need to use [`fileno`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno) to convert your `FILE*` to a file descriptor.