# What format does this log file is and is there a way to convert this?

Tags: go, format, nohup, logfile

This may be a noop question to ask but since I have no idea what and how to search for, I decided to to ask this to public. Please leave a comment if you think this question needs an improvement or need more information. I'll try to respond and edit as soon as possible.

I have this simple Go program that uses thirty party logging library called [zerolog](https://github.com/rs/zerolog) and prints logs.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
)

func init() {
    zerolog.SetGlobalLevel(zerolog.DebugLevel)
    zerolog.TimeFieldFormat = zerolog.TimeFormatUnixMs
    log.Logger = log.Output(zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stderr, TimeFormat: time.RFC3339Nano})
}

func main() {
    log.Debug().Msg("This if debugging message")
    log.Info().Msg("This is information message")
}
```

If you simply run this program with `$ go run main.go`, it prints out the following result.

```
2021-06-23T12:45:29.409Z DBG This if debugging message
2021-06-23T12:45:29.41Z INF This is information message
```

However, if I use `nohup` to run this program `$ nohup go run main.go &`, then it creates an output file called `nohup.out` and writes different log format. Why is that?

```
[90m2021-06-23T12:59:37.755Z[0m [33mDBG[0m This if debugging message
[90m2021-06-23T12:59:37.756Z[0m [32mINF[0m This is information message
```

Can anyone kindly explain to me what format this is and how do I convert this to human readable format like the first result?

Comment: It's not a different format, those are ANSI escape sequences for the color codes.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the quick comment. Then I believe I need to search for how do I do to convert ANSI escape sequences in go. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need to convert them in Go; you need to convert them wherever you're reading `nohup.out`.

Comment: For example, if you're reading the file with `less`, use `less -R` to have it render raw control characters. Instead of seeing the escape sequences in text, you'll see colored output.

Comment: I use `nano` to read the already generated `nohup.out` file. It shows the escape sequences in text. But like you said, using `less` to read the file renders the text well. I didn't even know the terminology `escape sequences`. That's great to know. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It is using the zerolog ConsoleWriter with color, so what you see in the second output is the escape sequences for colored output. You can turn color off (copied from zerolog examples):

```
func main() {
    out := zerolog.NewConsoleWriter()
    out.NoColor = true 
    log := zerolog.New(out)

    log.Debug().Str("foo", "bar").Msg("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: So basically this occurs due to the colorized output. Thank you so much! I wonder if there is a way to convert already generated file.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc