# How to get rid of backspace in a log file made the bash program "script"?

Tags: bash, sed, translate, backspace

I am logging a program (using the bash utility script) and I get outputs containing backspaces, where it was used, like:
"5,^H ^H.6"
instead of the final text: "5.6"

if I cat the log file I get the final "5.6", but if direct the result of cat into a file, and I open it with vi I still see "5,^H ^H.6"

Is there a way to save what I actually see using cat (make backspace really delete the character before)?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: With all the escape sequences, your question is more complex. Do you want to handle _only_ the backspace character, or do you want to handle _all_ ANSI escape sequences? In the first case, I think go with `sed`, in the second case, spawn a `tmux` terminal, execute `cat` in it, then save the terminal output to a file.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534556/how-to-remove-and-all-of-the-escape-sequences-in-a-file-using-linux-shell-sc

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
Using sed, I could handle other special characters like ^A, which appeared already 
ascii during typing. But when I type in the application that I am logging, backspace does not appear at all, it does delete back, as it should. It only appears in the log, but in return I cannot replace it with sed. Is it possible that it is some binary data, which is only translated to ^H ^H in vi?

Comment: `script` is a tool that can be invoked from any shell.  The fact that you invoke it from `bash` does not make it a "bash program".

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Ashok I have found the correct hex code for backspace:
https://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

```
sed 's/.\x08 \x08//g' log.out > log_without_backspaces.out
```

solved the problem, using just sed as KamilCuk suggested.
Many thanks!